# what is a good utility to "clean" up my Mac?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, cleaning, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cleaning Up Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/177206/cleaning-up-mac-os-x)

I recently read about [MacKeeper](http://mackeeper.zeobit.com/), a utility to optimize, clean up, secure, etc..., your Mac. I think this is a cool idea but I don't want to pay for this :)

So are there any similar programs/applications out there, preferably free?

Comment: The linked question is broader in scope, but there are tools recommended. Are there any specific issues? I don't use any real maintenance tools (see my answer in the linked topic) and have absolutely no problems with the same OS X user profile I created two machines and two major OS X versions ago, back in 2005.

Comment: No issues in particular... I just saw an ad for MacKeeper and I was curious to see the results. It said I had "critical" issues but I don't want to have to  pay for it b/c my Mac runs well. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

[OnyX](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) is worth looking into.